# websocket not working on tomcat 8

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, websocket, tomcat8

My project is working when deployed on intellij, however it is giving me an error
**failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404** when deployed on tomcat 8.
I saw some other posts saying that this might be an issue with jsr 356 libraries conflict.

This is my maven `dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ Web ---
[INFO] groupId:Web:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] \- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.545s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 01 08:46:35 AEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am new to maven and intellij so would appreciate any assistance with this issue

thanks

Comment: run: mvn dependency:tree on your project and post  the output.

Comment: Hi @JCCarrillo I have uploaded the requested information

Comment: I was hoping for more dependencies but your dependencies are okay. Can you share logs from your logs directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was quite simple, when my application was deployed on intellij locally using tomcat plugin the url was `http://localhost:8080/index.html` however when deployed on another tomcat the URL was `http://<server_address>:8080/<artifact_name>/index.html`

So at the end the problem was an URL mismatch.